# How to embed resource files at build in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I've a nuget package that has his own mvc control pannel, with controllers, views and routes.

This nuget package is imported in other .net core web applications.

At Visual Studio 2015, with .net core, I used the following code to compile the views as resources, allowing them to be found by razor engine and then rendered correctly.

At project.json (nuget):

```
 "buildOptions": {
    "embed": "**/Views/**/*.cshtml"
  }
```

At Startup.cs (web application):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.FileProviders.Add(new CompositeFileProvider(
            new EmbeddedFileProvider(
                typeof(HomeController).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
                "Some.Namespace"))
                    );
    });

    return new IuguPortalBuilder(services);
}
```

In Visual Studio 2017, the project.json file.doesn't exists anymore, and I'm unable to find find a new way to embed my views in the nuget package.

How can I embed my views?

Answer (score 16):

In `Solution Explorer` right click on desired file, click `Properties` and in opened window set `Build action` to `Embedded resource` - all like in old days :)

This will create following lines to your `*.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\Home\Index.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now MSBuild will add this file as embedded resource into your assembly.

Comment: Hi @Dmitry! Can I use a wildcard like "Views/*/*.cshtml" to import all my views at once?

Comment: @Carlos, I don't know, just try and share :)

Comment: Just tried on VS2017 : it worked for me with a format like `Include="**\Translations\Resource.*.resx"`

Comment: from solution explorer . setting build action to embed ressource didnt worked.  

so i manually edited csproj just like you showed here. with this method file can be anywhere on the disk.